# Blogger Code Image linking to post page

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, xml, blogger

Is this possible to achieve in blogger?

My goal is to make Static page images to become clickable and link it to the actual post page.

I know its possible by editing each post but I want to make it automatic. For example: In 9gag.com when you click the image from the homepage it will actually link you to the post page.

I want to do the same but in blogger. Something like this

```
<b:if cond='data:blog.pageType == "static_page"'><a expr:href='data:post.url'><static page images></a></b:if>
```

Screenshot: [image]

Comment: What's the structure of your HTML, specifically for the posts showing on the frontpage?

Answer (score 0):

Given that jQuery is available, you should be able to do it with something like this:

```
$('a.title').each(function() {
    var href = this.href;
    $(this).next('.article').find('img:not(a img)').each(function() {
        var a = $('<a/>', {
            'href': href
        });
        $(this).replaceWith(a);
        a.append(this);
    });
});
```

Of course not knowing the structure of your HTML, I just made up class names.

Comment: Thanks for the help sir. That was my 2nd option but luckily I found a way to do it using blogger codes.